# (Android Studio) The emulator process for AVD Pixel_7_API_34_2 has terminated

Tags: android, android-studio, settings

Hi i'm new with Android Studio and i got this problem "The emulator process for AVD Pixel_7_API_34_2 has terminated."

I got a:
AMD Ryzen 5 5600G with Radeon Graphics 3.90 GHz
GeForce GTX 1050ti
32 GB RAM
SSD 200 GB (179 GB Free)

I use Windows 10 Pro and i install Hyper-V. I set up my UEFI for virtualization. I change the settings in Windows security so it's allowed memory integrity.
In Android Studios i downloaded API 34 x86_64 and emulated performance change in graphics from auto to Hardware GLES 2.0.

I don't know what i missing. PLease help.

I use Windows 10 Pro and i install Hyper-V. I set up my UEFI for virtualization. I change the settings in Windows security so it's allowed memory integrity.
In Android Studios i downloaded API 34 x86_64 and emulated performance change in graphics from auto to Hardware GLES 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible solutions for your problem.

1.- Try "wipe data" on the emulator context menu.

2.- If that doesn't work, try cold boot.

3.- Try restarting the Android Studio IDE.

4.- Check the idea.log file located by default in C://Users/[your username]/Local/Google/AndroidStudio{version}/log/idea.log to get more info about the issue. Look for "Error" or "SEVERE" keywords, you will get a comprehensive description of the error cause.

5.- If nothing of the above works, try deleting your virtual device and creating anotherone.

Comment: I tried each of them, and none worked. I ran a virtual machine on Windows to rule out system virtualization, and it worked; it must be something related to Android Studio.
I can't find the '.log' file; the path you provided doesn't work.